# Populate Javascript array with PHP values and add quotes around each one

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following query to select the last five days price values:

```
$five_days_history = self::$db->select("SELECT CLOSE, TRADE_DATE
  FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE
  WHERE TRADE_DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND date <= CURDATE() and SYMBOL='$stock_symbol'
  ORDER BY TRADE_DATE DESC");
```

I need to get the TRADE_DATE output into the following type of JS array:

```
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
```

I want to replace the months with my date output. I try and get it into a comma separated list which works fine with the below code:

```
$five_day_ouput = array();
foreach ($five_days_history as $five_history) {
    $display_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($five_history['TRADE_DATE']));
    array_push($five_day_ouput, $display_date);
}
$five_day_ouput = implode(', ', $five_day_ouput);
```

When I do a `print_r` I get the following results:

> 06/08/2016, 06/07/2016, 06/06/2016, 06/05/2016, 06/04/2016, 06/03/2016

I then tried to replace my label with the following code:

```
labels: [<?php echo $five_day_output; ?>],
```

It isn't working because I don't have quotes around my values. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add the quotes to the date when you're converting it to another format.

Try replacing:

```
$display_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($five_history['TRADE_DATE']));
```

By:

```
$display_date = date('"m/d/Y"', strtotime($five_history['TRADE_DATE']));
```

Now when you do the `print_r`, instead of displaying:

> 06/08/2016, 06/07/2016, 06/06/2016, 06/05/2016, 06/04/2016, 06/03/2016

It should display:

> "06/08/2016", "06/07/2016", "06/06/2016", "06/05/2016", "06/04/2016", "06/03/2016"

Comment: Thanks, if I do that the results on the graph aren't as I expect when I use the new variable and put it in the labels as a PHP variable. However if I `print_r` the array and copy and paste that into the labels it outputs correctly. Any idea why it would do that and doesn't like it straight from the PHP variable?

Comment: Oops @RolandStarke ! Corrected :)

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm not sure what happened but your first answer works now.

Comment: The one where I asked your to add quotes @user1048676?

Comment: Well it's working because it's adding the double quotes to the date. But I thought you needed the date value somewhere else @user1048676?

Comment: I did but when I echo it with quotes as a string in the labels of JS it's working as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Just encode your array to json with `json_encode` php command.

`json_encode(['06/08/2016', '06/07/2016', '06/06/2016', '06/05/2016', '06/04/2016', '06/03/2016']);`

Comment: If I do this, the output to the screen is null. I tried `echo json_encode($five_day_output);`

Comment: are you sure that your `$five_day_output` is an array and not empty?

Comment: yes, if I do `print_r` for the array I get 06/08/2016, 06/07/2016, 06/06/2016, 06/05/2016, 06/04/2016, 06/03/2016

Comment: if it is an array you shoud receive something like this: `Array ( [0] => 06/08/2016 [1] => 06/07/2016 [2] => 06/06/2016 [3] => 06/05/2016 [4] => 06/04/2016 [5] => 06/03/2016 )` do you?
You also can check your variable `print_r(is_array($five_day_output));`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line where I was imploding it to get the commas which I thought I needed. When I do the json_encode, it still shows up weird on the graph. Only when I type the same string in manually does the graph show up correctly.

Comment: If it is already string - explode it in javascript `console.log(yourStrVariable.split(','))`

Comment: Use the browser feature: view source. You see `labels: [[` ? If yes then u know how to fix that I guess.